# How to set up a specific loop for aiohttp v3?

Tags: python, python-3.6, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I had set a `loop` for `aiohttp` while calling the `aiohttp.web.run_app(loop)` method in `v2.3`. However, after updating to `v3`, the parameter has disappeared and I couldn't find a way to set a specific loop.
(maybe only by `make_handler(loop)` but I want more high level API.)

Though there is `loop` parameter at `aiohttp.web.Application`, In the description of [aiohttp.web.Application](https://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web_reference.html#aiohttp.web.Application), it is saying on `loop` parameter like the below.

> loop –
>
> event loop
>
> Deprecated since version 2.0: The parameter is deprecated. Loop is get set during freeze stage.

What is `freeze state` in here?

As I look through the source code, it seems just to use default `loop`, calling `asyncio.get_event_loop()` internally.

Is there any different way to set up a specific `loop` for `aiohttp`?

## Edit

Here is my use-case.

1. In my app, it internally calls `loop.create_task`.
2. In v2.3, I gave specific `loop` to the app and use the `loop` so that all coroutines containing `aiohttp` run over the `loop`.
3. In v3, I could make it by making all coroutines use default `loop` so that all coroutines containing `aiohttp` run over the default `loop`.
4. However, when I run `unittest` with `AioHTTPTestCase`, it disables default `loop` internally and use new loop(`new_event_loop`).
5. As the result, other coroutines generate an error because they try to use default `loop` in the `unittest`.

I am thinking that I need some changes on my app if there is no way. However, before that, I just want to make sure it and why `aiohttp` group removes it.

Comment: Why do you need an event loop specifically for aiohttp?

Comment: Have you tried using `asyncio.set_event_loop`?

Comment: @user4815162342, I edit with my use-case.

Comment: You should probably make the unit tests use `asyncio.set_event_loop`

Answer (score 0):

Since cutting minimal supported version to Python 3.5.3 the test suite could be modified by setting test loop as default with `asyncio.set_event_loop()`.

The strange thing is how did you get not initialized event loop at all?
All initialization hooks (`self.get_application()`, `self.get_server()`, `self.get_client()`) are called inside a coroutine context, everything should work just perfect.

I see the only way -- you have installed aiohttp 3 on Python 3.5.1 or 3.5.2 maybe and use old setuptools version which ignores `python_requires` parameter.